# Python: Sort list of JSON by mm/dd/yyyy dates

Tags: python, json, date

I have data dump from a MongoDB cursor like sample:

```
>>> json_list
[{u'rDate': u'05/04/2009', u'_id': ObjectId('56c20bf2dc5e3753986b5564')},
{u'rDate': u'06/09/2009', u'_id': ObjectId('56c20be5dc5e3753986b5563')},
{u'rDate': u'12/08/2008', u'_id': ObjectId('56c20bf2dc5e3753986b5566')},
{u'rDate': u'12/21/2008', u'_id': ObjectId('56c20bf2dc5e3753986b5565')}]
```

Is there a way in Python to sort them in increasing order of dates? Like in the sample, the resulting sorted list would be:

```
>>> json_list
[{u'rDate': u'12/08/2008', u'_id': ObjectId('56c20bf2dc5e3753986b5566')},
{u'rDate': u'12/21/2008', u'_id': ObjectId('56c20bf2dc5e3753986b5565')},
{u'rDate': u'05/04/2009', u'_id': ObjectId('56c20bf2dc5e3753986b5564')},
{u'rDate': u'06/09/2009', u'_id': ObjectId('56c20be5dc5e3753986b5563')}]
```

I have looked at most of the related examples, but they have a date format like `"update_time": "1415387875"` which is not my case. Any help would be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: The sample data you've given is neither a valid python nor a valid JSON. What's your actual data format?

Comment: There's no 02/31/2014.

Comment: @LieRyan Pardon my attempts at synthesizing the data. I have updated the actual data dump from Mongo

Answer (score 5):

You got the wrong date 02/31/2014 (31 February). It is not possible

You can sort right dates like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

json_list = [{'id' : 5461, 'date': '02/14/2009'},
             {'id' : 5217, 'date': '09/25/2002'},
             {'id' : 5913, 'date': '02/28/2014'},
             {'id' : 5132, 'date': '01/07/2005'}]

sorted_date = sorted(json_list, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%m/%d/%Y'))
print sorted_date
```

Comment: Thanks, I cleaned it.

Comment: thanks, this is great. Sorry I was trying to synthesize data and that didn't go so well. But your solution should work like a charm and is also easy to understand. Didn't know we could use datetime in lambda sorting.

Comment: TypeError: string indices must be integers 
`sorted_date = sorted(json_string, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['modified'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the dates are a string and are always valid dates, then you can use [strptime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior). You can do something like:

```
json_list_sorted = sorted(json_list, key=lambda r: date.strptime(r["date"], "%m/%d/%Y"))
```

If you have invalid date and you still want to try to make sense of it, then it's a job for regular expression. Try to convert the date to ISO format first, whose lexicographical ordering (mostly) matches the date ordering (regex untested, but should give rough idea):

```
..., key=lambda r: re.sub(r"(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)", r"\3/\1/\2", r["date"]) ...
```

But you should try to fix your data source, it shouldn't be outputting invalid dates. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @timgeb Why should it?

Comment: @Selcuk because that date does not exist and strptime will raise an error.

Comment: @timgeb That's my point; it should raise an error instead of trying to actually compare it with a valid date.

Comment: @Selcuk OP wants to sort dates which can be invalid. Whether that's a good idea or not is another question.

Comment: @timgeb That was a typo, but what would you suggest? Is 02/31/2014 after 03/01/2014 or before?

Comment: @Selcuk I don't know, it does not make much sense either way. :)

Comment: @timgeb I believe raising an error is the way to go then :)

Comment: This conversation will be a reminder not to make such bewildering mistakes. Ever. :D